# R - using mixedorder from gtools

Tags: r

Can someone please help?

Here are two lines of R code which I would like to combine into one

```
smplA_Bacillus = subset(smplA, select = c(lab_id, Bacillus_C))
smplA_Bacillus = smplA_Bacillus[mixedorder(smplA_Bacillus$Bacillus_C),]
```

The mixedorder comes from gtools but what I am not sure if I the two commands can be used together.

When I try the following I get an error message

```
smplA_Bacillus = subset(smplA, select = c(lab_id, Bacillus_C))
smplA_Bacillus = smplA_Bacillus[mixedorder(subset(smplA, select = c(lab_id, Bacillus_C)$Bacillus_C),])
```

> Error: unexpected ']' in "smplA_Bacillus =
>   smplA_Bacillus[mixedorder(subset(smplA, select = c(lab_id,
>   Bacillus_C)$Bacillus_C),]"

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Either of these should do the same:

```
smplA_Bacillus = subset(smplA, select = c(lab_id, Bacillus_C) 
                               # select columns with subset
                                                      )[       #ordering with "["
                                               mixedorder(smplA_Bacillus$Bacillus_C), ]

 smplA_Bacillus = smplA[ mixedorder(smplA_Bacillus$Bacillus_C),
                                #ordering with the 'i' argument to"["
                                           c("lab_id", "Bacillus_C") ]
                                #selecting columns  with the j argument to "["
```